# null printing on console

Tags: selenium, log4j, webdriver

This is my log4j configuration file, whenever I run the batch file to execute the test case, a number of nulls are printed on the console. I have no experience with log4j, but I guess I have not assigned testAppender to ConsoleAppender, then why it is printing on console.

```
log4j.logger.com.rbs.rmd_test_suite.util.TestSuiteLogger=DEBUG, testAppender

log4j.appender.testAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.testAppender.File= ../log/rmd_test_suite_info.log
log4j.appender.testAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.testAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n
log4j.appender.testAppender.append=true

#Prevent internal log4j DEBUG messages from polluting the output.
log4j.logger.org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.log4j.FileAppender=INFO 

#Disabling logging of external jars 
log4j.rootLogger=Off
log4j.logger.org.openqa = OFF
```

I am using Selenium Web Driver API to automate test cases for an application. Any help is appreciated.

Logging in the file is perfectly fine. Problem is the nulls that are being printed on console.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible reason I can think of is, your log4j.properties file is not in the bin folder of your app.

Edited : Got it your rootLogger is OFF

```
log4j.rootLogger=Off
```

Instead use

```
log4j.rootLogger=ALL
log4j.logger.org.openqa=ALL
log4j.rootLogger=ALL, CA
log4j.appender.CA=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CA.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

Comment: Logging is being done perfectly fine in the file, apart from logging in file, nulls are being printed on console.

Comment: +1 for providing the answer, I will test it on monday. Bundles of thanks.

Comment: Bundles of thanks for providing the answer. I have tried this code, and it starts logging on the console, But my problem is that I do not want any sort of logging on console. I just want logging in the file which is doing file, but while logging in file nulls are printed on console. Just want to disable that printing of nulls on console.

Comment: Can you provide a snap shot of what you are seeing. Its difficult to comprehend.

Comment: Image attached, sorry to make it difficult to understand.

Comment: Do you have some kinda Log.error(object), where object is null ? I suspect that you are printing a object that is null. Cant think of anything else. Also put in the code for TestSuiteController, not all of it, but may be just the Log's or SOP's..